# VBA Copy and Paste Table from sheet 1 to sheet 2

Tags: excel, vba

I have 1 table “DataEntry” in sheet (1) the range is `A3:R20`
I want to paste it on my second sheet sheet(2) “Database” at cell "A3” and then clear the data entry table.

My current Marco is:

```
Sub CopyTable()

    Worksheets (1). ListObjects("DataEntry").Range.Copy _
    Destination:=Worksheets(2).Range ("A3")

End Sub
```

Comment: And ? What is the question ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to clear the data entry, without destroying the table, you can try the information from here: [How to select clear table contents without destroying the table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10220906/how-to-select-clear-table-contents-without-destroying-the-table) .

Otherwise, if you just want to clear the table completely, you can try:

```
Worksheets(1).ListObjects("DataEntry").Range.Clear  'or ClearContents
```