# Excel keeps running out of memory on table.Resize - Method Resize of object ListObject failed

Tags: excel, vba, memory, runtime-error, out-of-memory

fairly straightforward question:

I've got an excel `ListObject("list")`. It's part of a longer procedure - in particular it is launched from an `UserForm` that triggers this procedure upon every `Change`

What I'm trying to do, is: Simply clear the table and leave only the `.HeaderRowRange` unchanged.

```
Dim temp as Range
Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = Sheets("Pomocne")
Dim tbl As ListObject: Set tbl = ws2.ListObjects("list")

If Not tbl.DataBodyRange Is Nothing Then
     tbl.DataBodyRange.ClearContents
     Set temp = tbl.HeaderRowRange
     Set temp = temp.Resize(2)
     tbl.Resize temp
End If
```

Now this works all nice and fine. However, weird part is, if I change the `ComboBox` too many times, then suddenly the `Resize` method fails for seemingly no reason.

[image]

[image]

Additionally, if I try to check anything, I get a message that Excel has run out of memory.

[image]

Is there perhaps any way, I could re-size the table in a more memory friendly way that would not result in an error after multiple changes? Or perhaps am I resizing the table range incorrectly?

Comment: What is the value of `temp`?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie well it is a range, consisting of multiple cells, so `temp` as in within itself would return `Nothing`.. Upon the crash/error, the `temp.Address` returns `$B$2:$G$3` which is the correct range.

Comment: Perhaps should have worded that comment better, not `Nothing`, but given it consists of multiple cells, it would nto be possible to print `.Value`

Comment: There must be something else in your code, cause I couldn't replicate the error. Maybe check this answer for resizing/clearing a listboject: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10220906/how-to-select-clear-table-contents-without-destroying-the-table