# Find and copy last row to another worksheet + indefinitely backup of line when macro is activated

Tags: excel, vba

**The situation:**

I have modified a workbook that contains a stopwatch. This tool is to monitor the downtimes of lines in a factory. It has, now (and I don't plan to create more worksheets):
- Info (for explaining how to use it);
- Ref (for putting references that may be/will be editable by the user);
- StopWatch (Which contain the clock, start/pause/stop+record buttons, and the table to register it);
- ghist (A 'ghost history', that will act as a backup for every time recorded ever in that spreadsheet;
- Calc (That is an 'imported' table from the StopWatch sheet, so some calculations can be done without screwing the Stopwatch sheet).

**How the workbook behave**

- Info: doesn't matter, its pure informative;
- Ref: It's the with time reference for the clock, columns with options for the data validation lists; in the cell, A1 is protected to now destroy the reference for the clock;
- Stopwatch: you select some options within the available data validation lists and write (just a speed value) in column C, Line, machine, product, etc. Then you start the clock, with a button, can pause it, with another, and then stop it, to register the passed time. The registering region starts in F3 and ends on the column S. After finishing measuring the data, you can import it to the 'Calc' sheet (I'm just copying the values) and then, if you want to use it again, you can clean the table on the StopWatch sheet, to register new data.
  In the 'background' of the workbook I, after every STOP clicked, want it to make a copy of that line (the last one on the table of the StopWatch worksheet, the last measurement), as a safety backup.

**My Problems:**

It is a common one, but after days of trying and error I couldn't figure it out, it is simple, but I can't overcome this. Putting in a list again:

- I managed to 'Frankstein' the code, I can copy the last line and paste it on the next empty row in the backup sheet, but, after I CLEAN the main table of the StopWatch sheet when I start to record the time again, it overwrites the existing lines, starting from the line 2.
- When copied the values are paste in the F column, I want them in column A.
- There are times when I run the macro, in the backup sheet, the code write, copies the last line of the main table and paste in the backup after stopping the clock, if I run it again I copies no the last, but the one before, 1 & 2, then I run it again, it copies 1, 2 & 3, and keep like this.
- If I measure some points, then import to calc, clean the table and then import again, this new import process will overwrite the existing points.
- Could export the calc table to a csv file, f

**My Assumptions**

- I put everything in one module alone;
- This code is a combination of codes, some notations may not correlate
- I may have used some unnecessary functions/mods, but I tried everything I could to get here
- I commented on every line I could to try to show what I was understanding in that place.

I appreciate ANY help on this. Thanks a lot in advance.

**The code**

````
Option Explicit

'Source: https://trumpexcel.com/stopwatch-in-excel/

'-----------------------------------------------------

'Definition of the variable of the time running in the clock
Dim NextTick As Date
Dim t As Date
Dim PreviousTimerValue As Date


Sub Start()

'-----------------------------------------------------

'Unlock the reference cell A1, on Ref Sheet, to be used in the counting of time
Ref.Unprotect Password:="timeref"

'Check the reference time and "free it to run" so the time pass
PreviousTimerValue = Ref.Range("A1").Value
t = Time
Call ExcelStopWatch

'-----------------------------------------------------

End Sub

Private Sub ExcelStopWatch()

'-----------------------------------------------------

'Check the reference time (Cell A1 on Ref), changes the color of the clock acording to the parameters in the Ref sheet
Ref.Range("A1").Value = Format(Time - t + PreviousTimerValue, "hh:mm:ss")
NextTick = Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")

'Green color
If Ref.Range("A1").Value > Ref.Range("B3") And Ref.Range("A1").Value <= Ref.Range("B4") Then
    With StopWatch.Shapes("TimeBox")
        .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 255, 0)
    End With

'Yellow color
Else
    If Ref.Range("A1").Value > Ref.Range("B4") And Ref.Range("A1").Value <= Ref.Range("B5") Then
    With StopWatch.Shapes("TimeBox")
        .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 0)
    End With

'Red color
Else
    If Ref.Range("A1").Value > Ref.Range("B5") Then
    With StopWatch.Shapes("TimeBox")
        .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    End With
End If
End If
End If

Application.OnTime NextTick, "ExcelStopWatch"

'-----------------------------------------------------


End Sub

Sub Pause()

'Pause command in the clock
On Error Resume Next
Application.OnTime earliesttime:=NextTick, procedure:="ExcelStopWatch", schedule:=False

End Sub

Sub StopReset()

'-----------------------------------------------------

'Stop command that also will copy the parameters defined on the StopWatch worksheet to the main table
On Error Resume Next

'Reset the background color or the clock to white
With StopWatch.Shapes("TimeBox")
        .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    End With

'Copy commands, to write down every variable:
If StopWatch.Range("F3") = "" And Ref.Range("A1").Value > 0 Then
    StopWatch.Range("F3").Value = 1                                             'To write the order numbers
    StopWatch.Range("F3").Offset(0, 1).Value = Ref.Range("A1").Value            'To write the duration
    StopWatch.Range("F3").Offset(0, 2).Value = Date + Time                      'To write the Date + Time
    StopWatch.Range("F3").Offset(0, 3).Value = StopWatch.Range("C15").Value     'To copy the Line Name
    StopWatch.Range("F3").Offset(0, 4).Value = StopWatch.Range("C16").Value     'To copy the Machine
    StopWatch.Range("F3").Offset(0, 5).Value = StopWatch.Range("C17").Value     'To copy the Product
    StopWatch.Range("F3").Offset(0, 6).Value = StopWatch.Range("C18").Value     'To copy the Type of Cover
    StopWatch.Range("F3").Offset(0, 7).Value = StopWatch.Range("C19").Value     'To copy the Bottle Size
    StopWatch.Range("F3").Offset(0, 8).Value = StopWatch.Range("C20").Value     'To copy the Bottle Model
    StopWatch.Range("F3").Offset(0, 9).Value = StopWatch.Range("C21").Value     'To copy the Box Formation
    StopWatch.Range("F3").Offset(0, 10).Value = StopWatch.Range("C22").Value    'To copy the Speed of the line
    StopWatch.Range("F3").Offset(0, 11).Value = StopWatch.Range("C23").Value    'To copy the Shift

Else:

'To identify the last used row and use the one after that
    StopWatch.Range("F2").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Value = StopWatch.Range("F2").End(xlDown).Value + 1  'To write the order numbers
    StopWatch.Range("F2").Offset(0, 1).End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Value = Ref.Range("A1").Value           'To write the duration
    StopWatch.Range("F2").Offset(0, 2).End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Value = Date + Time                     'To write the Date + Time
    StopWatch.Range("F2").Offset(0, 3).End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Value = StopWatch.Range("C15").Value    'To copy the Line Name
    StopWatch.Range("F2").Offset(0, 4).End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Value = StopWatch.Range("C16").Value    'To copy the Machine
    StopWatch.Range("F2").Offset(0, 5).End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Value = StopWatch.Range("C17").Value    'To copy the Product
    StopWatch.Range("F2").Offset(0, 6).End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Value = StopWatch.Range("C18").Value    'To copy the Type of Cover
    StopWatch.Range("F2").Offset(0, 7).End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Value = StopWatch.Range("C19").Value    'To copy the Bottle Size
    StopWatch.Range("F2").Offset(0, 8).End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Value = StopWatch.Range("C20").Value    'To copy the Bottle Model
    StopWatch.Range("F2").Offset(0, 9).End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Value = StopWatch.Range("C21").Value    'To copy the Box Formation
    StopWatch.Range("F2").Offset(0, 10).End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Value = StopWatch.Range("C22").Value   'To copy the Speed of the Line
    StopWatch.Range("F2").Offset(0, 11).End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Value = StopWatch.Range("C23").Value   'To copy the Shift


End If


'-----------------------------------------------------

'Reset the value of the clock to zero
Application.OnTime earliesttime:=NextTick, procedure:="ExcelStopWatch", schedule:=False
Ref.Range("A1").Value = 0

'-----------------------------------------------------

'Protect the cell of reference for the time, A1 on sheet Ref
Ref.Protect Password:="timeref"


'-----------------------------------------------------


'Backup of use, should copy all the lines that once was "stoped" by the button click, the last line of the main table near the clock

'IDK what this line do, but made the 'flickering' of the screen stop.
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Defining the variable to find the last row in the main table and in the ghost history (backup)
Dim lastrowSrc As Long
Dim lastrowDest As Long


'Get last row of data
lastrowSrc = Sheets("StopWatch").Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

'Get first blank row (last row of data +1)
lastrowDest = Sheets("gHist").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

'Copy row
Sheets("StopWatch").Range("F3:S" & lastrowSrc).EntireRow.Copy Sheets("ghist").Range("A" & lastrowDest)

'Complement of the code to stop the flickering when copying te line.
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True


'-----------------------------------------------------


End Sub


'-----------------------------------------------------

'To clear the main table of the StopWatch

Sub ResetMT()

'Definying the worksheets I'm working with
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet


'declare an object variable to hold a reference to cells to clear
Dim LRS_Reset As Long
Dim LRB_Reset As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Warning message to confirm exclusion
If MsgBox("These changes cannot be undone. This will erase everything! Are you sure?", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then Exit Sub

'Source of the data
Set ws1 = Sheets("StopWatch")

'Backup Sheet
Set ws2 = Sheets("ghist")

'My tentative to "show" to the stop button the last used row, I think it was 'erasing' the capacity of the code to know the last used row in the backup sheet (ghist)
LRS_Reset = ws1.Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

'Comment to myself, learning while making the reset of the main table not erease the headers
'OBS: If you add "+1" after .Row you will keep the headings in case the file is empty. [if it is empty and the code runs without "+1" it will erase the headings]

'Definition of the clearing range, this method keeps the formatting style
Range("F3:S" & LRS_Reset).ClearContents

'Attempt to show the code the last used row in the ghist (backup sheet)
LRB_Reset = ws2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

'Copied from above to stop the flickering (hope its correct)
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

'-----------------------------------------------------


End Sub

'-----------------------------------------------------

'To import the captured table for the calculations

Sub ImportMT()

'Warning message to confirm exclusion
If MsgBox("This will import the current data for calculation. Are you sure?", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then Exit Sub

Range("F3", Range("F3").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)).Copy Worksheets("Calc").Range("A2")

'-----------------------------------------------------

End Sub


'-----------------------------------------------------

'Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10220906/how-to-select-clear-table-contents-without-destroying-the-table
'To clear the content of the calc sheet without losing the headers and style/table

Sub ResetCalcTab()

'Warning message to confirm exclusion
If MsgBox("These changes cannot be undone. This will erase everything on this table! Are you sure?", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then Exit Sub

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Sheets("Calc").Select
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Calc").HeaderRowRange.Select

'Remove the filters if one exists.
If ActiveSheet.FilterMode Then
Selection.AutoFilter
End If

'Clear all lines but the first one in the table leaving formulas for the next to go round.
With Worksheets("Calc").ListObjects("Calc")
.Range.AutoFilter
On Error Resume Next
.DataBodyRange.Offset(1).Resize(.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count - 1, .DataBodyRange.Columns.Count).Rows.Delete
.DataBodyRange.Rows(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).ClearContents
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-10000

End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

'-----------------------------------------------------

End Sub```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the first bullet in the problems list, you mentioned that the data is getting pasted to Column F in the "gHist" sheet. However, you are looking for the last row from column A which will be empty and return 2. This is why is keeps overwriting.

Regarding the second bullet in your Problems list, you are copying the entire row so it will paste the values in the same columns as they appear on the "StopWatch" sheet.

Regarding the third bullet, you are starting with "F3" in your copy range meaning it will copy the whole table rather than the last row.

Instead, try this to fix all the above issues:

```
'Copy row
Sheets("StopWatch").Range("F" & lastrowSrc & ":S" & lastrowSrc).Copy Sheets("ghist").Range("A" & lastrowDest)
```

Additionally, you may want to remove (or use very sparingly) the

```
On Error Resume Next
```

as this will ignore errors and continuing running. The error messages will help you determine what is wrong.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help @pjensen ! Now the code is working flawlessly. The only small detail I couldn`t make it work was that, in the Calc sheet, I have the table there (Object named calc also) that keeps the line 2 empty after I import the data to it. It's manageable, but do have any insight in what could be the trick there? another small detail I am missing?

Comment: Is it missing data, or is the data just shifted down to row 3?

Comment: It is just pasted from row 3 to down, I tried many times, but I can't make it be imported to row 2 and then keep using the next free one. This specific one is a table (ListObject), maybe there is something more tricky in the middle?